# How to find a value that match a first condition from mulpitple conditions

Tags: ruby

For example there is a array like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

I want to find a value that is `2`, but if that doesn't exist find a `3` and so on `5`.

```
result = a.find{|i| i == 2} || a.find{|i| i == 3} || a.find{|i| i == 5}
```

Of course the real values are more complicated, Can I write the function more succinct?

Comment: Do you want to do this? `[2, 3, 5].find{|i| a.include?(i)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using separate validators that encapsulate each condition. It will help you decouple your business logic.

Consider this - instead of Integer array you have Car class instances

```
class Car
    attr_accessor :producer, :colour, :max_speed

    def initialize(producer, colour, max_speed)
        @producer = producer
        @colour = colour
        @max_speed = max_speed
    end
end
```

Now you want to select cars, by max_speed, colour and lastly by producer

```
cars = [
    Car.new(:ford, :black, 200),
    Car.new(:fiat, :yellow, 170),
    Car.new(:renault, :green, 200),
]
```

instead of putting all conditions in one place, use separate validators

```
class ColourValidator
    def initialize(colour)
        @colour = colour
    end

    def matching?(car)
        car.colour == @colour
    end
end

class MaxSpeedValidator
    def initialize(max_speed)
        @max_speed = max_speed
    end

    def matching?(car)
        car.max_speed == @max_speed
    end
end

class ProducerValidator
    def initialize(producer)
        @producer = producer
    end

    def matching?(car)
        car.producer == @producer
    end
end
```

of course vaidators may be much more complex - this is just an idea

and no in one place you create validators

```
validators = [
    ProducerValidator.new(:renault)
]
```

and later in your code you may write

```
cars.find { |car| validators.any? { |v| v.matching?(car) } }
```

benefit is here you don't have to check concrete business logic but just the mechanism of returning element for which any validator matches. Additionally when new validator comes up - you just have to test its logic without reference to the rest

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array#&](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26):

```
([2,3,5] & [1,2,3]).first #=> 2
([0,3,5] & [1,2,3]).first #=> 3
([0,4,5] & [1,2,3]).first #=> nil
```

From the doc: "The order is preserved from the original array."

@argus' suggestion (in a comment) should not be overlooked.